# How to get AJAX values in Java

Tags: java, ajax, restlet

I'm doing an `ajax` call to my server, and need to get the values from it. How is this done?

This is the `ajax`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "http://localhost:8080/myapp/etc",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: {"id": "1", "somekey": "somevalue"},
    dataType: "json",
    async: "true",
    success: function(msg) {
        alert("success " + msg);
    },

    error: function(msg) {
        alert("error " + msg.toString());
    }
});
```

I'm working with `Restlets` so I'm assuming the values would be in the Representation entity. This is the method:

```
@Post
public Representation doPost(Representation entity) {
    String et = java.net.URLDecoder.decode(entity.getText(), "UTF-8");
    System.out.println("the entity text " + et);
}
```

This prints out `"id": "1", "somekey": "somevalue"`. But how do I get the other values? The `async`, the `url`, etc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Restlet will give you access about the elements sent within the request (URL, headers, payload) but not to client-side configuration properties to build the request.

You can have a look at what is sent in the request for your AJAX call using tool like Chome console or Firebug.

The property `async` isn't sent within the request, so you can't get it from server side. For the URL, you can use this code within a server resource:

```
Reference reference = getRequest().getResourceRef();
String url = reference.toString();
```

For more details, have a look at javadocs for the class `Reference`: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/javadocs/2.1/jee/api/org/restlet/data/Reference.html. This class allows you to have access to each element within it (host domain, port, path, ...).

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Answer (score 1):

The `async` is a client-side directive telling the client not to block while the ajax call is processed. The server doesn't know or care about this.

Getting the URL is possible server side using something like `String url = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURL().toString();`

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like this, using the org.restlet.ext.json extension:

```
@Post
public Representation handle(JsonObject jo) {
    System.out.println(jo.getString("id"));
    System.out.println(jo.getString("somekey"));
    return ...;
}
```